# pandas python add columns from other data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make a df that in the end of the df, there are columns that gets their data from revious dfs.
I want to check in other dfs, if the ids in the first columns exists there, if so, check in which columns they appear, and add it to the last column in the main df.

EXAMPLE:

I have a **MAIN DF** that looks like so:

```
names    col1   col2   col3   total
 bbb      V      V      X      2
 ccc      V      X      X      1
 zzz      X      V      V      2
 qqq      X      V      X      1
 rrr      X      X      V      1
```

and for example I have two more dfs (in general there are more then just two more dfs, so I want to run on all of them in a loop or something), **DF1**:

```
names    col1   col4   col5   total
 bbb      V      V      X      2
 ccc      V      X      X      1
 yyy      V      V      X      2
```

and **DF2**:

```
names    col6   col2   col7   total
 bbb      V      V      X      2
 ccc      X      X      V      1
 zzz      X      V      V      2
```

so I want to update my **MAIN DF** to look like so:

```
names    col1   col2   col3   total   total_col1   total_col2
 bbb      V      V      X      2         DF1           DF1           
                                         DF2           DF2
 ccc      V      X      X      1         DF1                        
 zzz      X      V      V      2                       DF2     
 qqq      X      V      X      1
 rrr      X      X      V      1
```

I hope there is possibility to do so in pandas and that the example was clear

**EDIT:** notice to the columns: in `DF1` and `DF2` there are also other columns that aren't in the original main DF, so I added only the columns that are also in the original main DF.

Comment: One question - row with `ccc` can be in 2 rows like row with `aaa`?

Comment: @jezrael no, it cannot, each names is only once in a df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use more general another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44225586/2901002).

First create `list` `dfs` of `DataFrames` and in list comprehension process them. Then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) them together and again use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df_names = ['DF1', 'DF2']
cols = ['col1','col2','col3']

dfs = [DF1, DF2]
dfs = [x.set_index('names')[cols]
        .replace({'V':df_names[i], 'X':np.nan})
        .add_prefix('total_') for i, x in enumerate(dfs)]
DF_ALL = pd.concat(dfs)
print (DF_ALL) 
      total_col1 total_col2 total_col3
names                                 
bbb          DF1        DF1        NaN
ccc          DF1        NaN        NaN
yyy          DF1        DF1        NaN
bbb          DF2        DF2        NaN
ccc          NaN        NaN        DF2
zzz          NaN        DF2        DF2

df = df.join(DF_ALL, on='names')
print (df)
  names col1 col2 col3  total total_col1 total_col2 total_col3
0   bbb    V    V    X      2        DF1        DF1        NaN
0   bbb    V    V    X      2        DF2        DF2        NaN
1   ccc    V    X    X      1        DF1        NaN        NaN
1   ccc    V    X    X      1        NaN        NaN        DF2
2   zzz    X    V    V      2        NaN        DF2        DF2
3   qqq    X    V    X      1        NaN        NaN        NaN
4   rrr    X    X    V      1        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

EDIT:

Solution with no `names` columns:

```
df_names = ['DF1', 'DF2']
cols = ['col1','col2','col3']

dfs = [DF1, DF2]
dfs = [x[cols].replace({'V':df_names[i], 'X':np.nan})
              .add_prefix('total_') for i, x in enumerate(dfs)]
DF_ALL = pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().tolist()))
print (DF_ALL) 
    total_col1 total_col2 total_col3
bbb   DF1, DF2   DF1, DF2           
ccc        DF1                   DF2
yyy        DF1        DF1           
zzz                   DF2        DF2

df = pd.merge(df, DF_ALL, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
df[DF_ALL.columns] = df[DF_ALL.columns].fillna('')
print (df)

    col1 col2 col3  total total_col1 total_col2 total_col3
bbb    V    V    X      2   DF1, DF2   DF1, DF2           
ccc    V    X    X      1        DF1                   DF2
zzz    X    V    V      2                   DF2        DF2
qqq    X    V    X      1                                 
rrr    X    X    V      1
```

EDIT1:

Solution with exclude cols - use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) with `list` and `errors='ignore'` for no error if column is missing:

```
dfs = [DF1, DF2]
df_names = ['DF1', 'DF2']

exclude_cols = ['total','col_aaa']


dfs = [x.drop(exclude_cols, axis=1, errors='ignore')
        .replace({'V':df_names[i], 'X':np.nan})
        .add_prefix('total_') for i, x in enumerate(dfs)]
DF_ALL = pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().tolist()))
print (DF_ALL) 
    total_col1 total_col2 total_col3
bbb   DF1, DF2   DF1, DF2           
ccc        DF1                   DF2
yyy        DF1        DF1           
zzz                   DF2        DF2

df = pd.merge(df, DF_ALL, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
df[DF_ALL.columns] = df[DF_ALL.columns].fillna('')
print (df)
    col1 col2 col3  total total_col1 total_col2 total_col3
bbb    V    V    X      2   DF1, DF2   DF1, DF2           
ccc    V    X    X      1        DF1                   DF2
zzz    X    V    V      2                   DF2        DF2
qqq    X    V    X      1                                 
rrr    X    X    V      1
```

EDIT2: Added filtering of columns by [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
print (DF2.columns.intersection(df.columns))
Index(['col2', 'total'], dtype='object')

dfs = [DF1, DF2]
df_names = ['DF1', 'DF2']

exclude_cols = ['total','col_aaa']

dfs = [x[x.columns.intersection(df.columns)].drop(exclude_cols, axis=1, errors='ignore')
        .replace({'V':df_names[i], 'X':np.nan})
        .add_prefix('total_') for i, x in enumerate(dfs)]
DF_ALL = pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().tolist()))
print (DF_ALL) 
    total_col1 total_col2
bbb        DF1        DF2
ccc        DF1           
yyy        DF1           
zzz                   DF2

df = pd.merge(df, DF_ALL, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
df[DF_ALL.columns] = df[DF_ALL.columns].fillna('')
print (df)
    col1 col2 col3  total total_col1 total_col2
bbb    V    V    X      2        DF1        DF2
ccc    V    X    X      1        DF1           
zzz    X    V    V      2                   DF2
qqq    X    V    X      1                      
rrr    X    X    V      1
```

Comment: and if I want to have one row, and not to have dupliacte rows with the same name? like, merging a row with the same name, and just add a new line between `DF1 DF2` in the `total` columns?

Comment: I am having some trouble doing so, because in my real data, the index column don't have any name at all, so I get an error: `KeyError: 'names'`. I tried to call the index column like so `df.index.name = 'names'` but didn't work. so how can I do it when my index column has no name?

Comment: everything is the same as in the example, except for the part that there is no name for the index column. so there is no `'names'` column.  (not in the DF1.columns and not in the DF2.columns)

Comment: thanks it's almost there, but I guess I wasn't so clear. I have an error saying `KeyError ... not in index` which comes from `.add_prefix('total_') for i, x in enumerate(dfs)]` this is because there are columns in DF1 and in DF2, that may not be in the `cols` list and vice versa. how can it be fix?

Comment: the problem is just what you said - some columns in some dataframes are missing. so yes, I think that exclude cols should do the job. what is the way to use them?

Comment: in the `exclude_cols` I need to add all the columns that are in `DF1` and `DF2` but not in `df`? what columns I want to 'exclude'?

Comment: but what columns should I put inside the list? the columns that in `df` and not in `DF1` and `DF2` or the columns that are in `DF1` and `DF2` and not in `df`?

Comment: but then it gives me an empty df, if sometimes `DF1` and `df` has exact same columns.

Comment: so for example, `DF1` has cols: `col1` only, and `df` has `col1 col2 col3` so I will add to `df` only `total_col1`, or `DF1` has cols: `col1 col2 col3`, and `df` has `col1` only so I will add to `df` only `total_col1`. or: both has same columns or both has no col in common.

Comment: yes there `DF2` and even more, but the logic is the same and I do it in a loop. and for the second question I didn't understand

Comment: made an edit to the question. hope now it is more clear

Comment: Please check solution.

Comment: what if instead of displaying in the cell in which DFs it's shown, I want to count it, what changes to do? for example, instead of showing `DF1, DF2` I want to count it so it will be: `2`. what I need to change? I tried but nothing works for me

Comment: I think the best is create new question, is it possible? Because I think it is not good idea still working in one answer. Especially if it is really hard like this.

Comment: sure thanks, look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543409/python-pandas-manipulating-dataframe  hopes it is more clear

Answer (score 0):

It can work for you :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

MAIN_DF = [["bbb","V","V","X",2],
           ["ccc","V","X","X",1],
           ["zzz","X","V","V",2],
           ["qqq","X","V","X",1],
           ["rrr","X","X","V",1]]
MAIN_DF = pd.DataFrame(MAIN_DF, columns=["names", "col1","col2","col3","total"])

DF1 = [["bbb","V","V","X"],
       ["ccc","V","X","X"],
       ["yyy","V","V","X"]]
DF1 = pd.DataFrame(DF1, columns=["names", "col1","col2","col3"])
DF2 = [["bbb","V","V","X"],
       ["ccc","X","X","V"],
       ["zzz","X","V","V"]]
DF2 = pd.DataFrame(DF2, columns=["names", "col1","col2","col3"])


total_col = pd.DataFrame(data = np.zeros((MAIN_DF.shape[0],MAIN_DF.shape[1]-1)), columns=["names", "col1","col2","col3"])
total_col["names"]=MAIN_DF["names"] 


for i in xrange(total_col.shape[0]):
    name = total_col["names"][i]
    for j in xrange(DF1.shape[0]):
        if DF1["names"][j] == name:
            for col in DF1.columns[1:]:
                if DF1[col][j] == "V":
                    total_col[col][i] = "DF1"


for i in xrange(total_col.shape[0]):
    name = total_col["names"][i]
    for j in xrange(DF2.shape[0]):
        if DF2["names"][j] == name:
            for col in DF2.columns[1:]:
                if DF2[col][j] == "V":
                    if total_col[col][i] == "DF1":
                        total_col[col][i] = "DF1 DF2"
                    else:
                        total_col[col][i] = "DF2"

  names     col1     col2 col3
0   bbb  DF1 DF2  DF1 DF2    0
1   ccc      DF1        0  DF2
2   zzz        0      DF2  DF2
3   qqq        0        0    0
4   rrr        0        0    0
```