# Python Pandas match two indexes and value of column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to match between indexes of rows in two different dfs, and if the indexes are the same, I want to go to the second df, iterate through it's columns, and if the value of a column is 'V', go to the first df, and add the name of the df to the value of a column.

so for example:

**MAIN DF:**

```
names    col1   col2   col3   total
 bbb      V      V      X      2
 ccc      V      X      X      1
```

**DF2:**

```
names    col1   col2   col3   total
 bbb      V      V      X      2
 zzz      X      X      V      1
```

so after the **MAIN DF** will be:

```
names    col1   col2   col3   total   totla_col1   total_col2   total_col3
 bbb      V      V      X      2          DF2          DF2         NULL
 ccc      V      X      X      1          NULL         NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first create index from `names` column by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) values by `dict` and [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html).

Then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) it to original:

```
cols = ['col1','col2','col3']
DF2 = DF2.set_index('names')[cols].replace({'V':'DF2', 'X':np.nan}).add_prefix('total_')
print (DF2) 
      total_col1 total_col2 total_col3
names                                 
bbb          DF2        DF2        NaN
zzz          NaN        NaN        DF2

df = df.join(DF2, on='names')
print (df)
  names col1 col2 col3  total total_col1 total_col2 total_col3
0   bbb    V    V    X      2        DF2        DF2        NaN
1   ccc    V    X    X      1        NaN        NaN        NaN
```